# Differentiating between page first load, refresh, postback, and using a generated link

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh, postback, pageload

**Intro Info**

When I started this problem my main goal was to tell the difference between a first time page load and a page refresh so I could set filter settings on page components appropriately.

After digging through many posts and articles on how to detect the differences, I found out that my case was a little different than everything I came across.  I did come up with a working solution.  *The actual question is at the bottom of the post*.

My web application allows users to make selections on a page that determine what info to pull from a database and display it onto the page.  The user can also set filters on the components that display the data.

---

**Requirements**

- When a page is visited for the first time it shouldn't have any filters set.
- When a page is refreshed (*eg: F5*) the filters should be restored.
- When a link (generated from the app) is used the filters should be set the same way from the linked page.
- When a `post-back` happens the filters should remain the same.

---

**What I Did**

Setting the filter settings when first loading a page and using a generated link was already taken care of, but I had to detect them so I didn't override them.

I mainly handled this in the `Page_Load` function.

```
if (!IsPostBack){ // Happens on first page load, generated link, and page refresh
    if (Request.QueryString["gridLayout"] == null){ // Query strings are for link

        // Now check if first page load or page refresh
        // See if there are saved filters to load - yes means refresh
        if (this.Session["refreshStaticGridLayout"] != null && 
            !(this.Session["refreshStaticGridLayout"].ToString().Equals(""))){
            // Load the filter settings
            MainGrid.LoadClientLayout(
                this.Session["refreshStaticGridLayout"].ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

- Loading a page from a generated link utilizes `query strings` - basically if there was a `query string` then move on.
- Every time the user changes the filter settings I set a `Session` variable to store them.

---

**Question**

**I want to know if anyone thinks that this is a logically bad way, knows a better way, or knows a corner case that would break this.**  I'm asking because a lot of the posts about how to handle detecting page refreshes were clearly labeled as just workarounds and there seems to be a lot of murky ways to go about doing this.  Thank you.

---

**Edit**

I'm not concerned about the `Session` with the client expiring.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but I believe you will lose all session variables after your session times out on server (if you have not changed any settings, then it is set to 20 minutes). Say your user loaded info and then went to get a cup a coffee, met someone, talked too long. Then they come back, and oops, all is lost. of course this is a hypothetical situation.

Comment: Good point, thank you for the info, but I don't have to worry about this case. Different features done by others before me also use the `Session` as well since they decided not to worry about supporting extended periods of time.